# Se me presenta un problema al querer obtener la información de un jtexbox en otro frame

Tags: java

Quiero obtener el valor de un textbox de otro form pero me da vacio, este es el codigo del frame Aplication2 donde quiero acceder a dicha información

```
ProyectoAplication b = new ProyectoAplication();
  public void Mostrar(){
        String x = (String)b.jTextFieldNumeroDeEcuaciones.getText();
        int NumeroDeEcuaciones = Integer.parseInt(x);
            for (int i = 0; i < NumeroDeEcuaciones; i++) {
              JTextField input = new JTextField("texto por defecto",20); 
              this.add(input);
            } 
    }
```

y este es el codigo del frame ProyectoAplication donde invoco al otro frame Aplication2

```
   private void ButtonIniciarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    new Aplication2().setVisible(true);
    this.setVisible(false);
}
```

Comment: el Form2 que te puse es Aplication2 creale un constructor con un parametro String o ProyectoAplication y se lo pasas si no tendrás sus datos.

Comment: @ReyJuanjo no te entiendo, si puedes editar tu respuesta con lo que me dices te lo agradecería mucho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas inicializando un nuevo objeto del tipo ProyectoAplication, no son los datos del que tienes abierto.

```
ProyectoAplication b = new ProyectoAplication();
```

Imagino que desde el form de ProyectoAplication abres el "Form2"(donde esta la función "Mostrar"), pues deberías definirle un constructor que reciba o bien un ProyectoAplication o bien un String(con el valor del TextField que quieres utilizar en este otro form).

```
Form2 b = new Form2(this);
```

o

```
Form2 b = new Form2(jTextFieldNumeroDeEcuaciones.getText());
```

Siendo Form2:

```
    public class Form2 extends JFrame{
    private ProyectoAplication b; //o String b;
      Form2(ProyectoAplication pr )//o String pr
    {
          b=pr;
    }
      public void Mostrar(){
            String x = (String)b.jTextFieldNumeroDeEcuaciones.getText();
            int NumeroDeEcuaciones = Integer.parseInt(x);
                for (int i = 0; i < NumeroDeEcuaciones; i++) {
                  JTextField input = new JTextField("texto por defecto",20); 
                  this.add(input);
                } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: igual me da error

Comment: Debes dar algo más de info

Comment: hice lo que me dijiste pero ` private ProyectoAplication b; 
        Aplication2(ProyectoAplication pr ){
          b=pr;
        }
    public void Mostrar(){
            String x = (String)b.jTextFieldNumeroDeEcuaciones.getText();
            int NumeroDeEcuaciones = Integer.parseInt(x);
                for (int i = 0; i < NumeroDeEcuaciones; i++) {
                  JTextField input = new JTextField("texto por defecto",20); 
                  this.add(input);
                } 
   }` pero igual error

Comment: en ProyectoAplication defino esto Form2 b = new Form2(jTextFieldNumeroDeEcuaciones.getText());?

Comment: Form2 es un nombre que te dije, no se si se llamara así tu form, deberías adjuntar mas info en la pregunta.

Comment: listo @ReyJuanjo